# Equivalent definition for direct sum for $k$ subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could anyone tell me if this statement is true or not?

Considering a vector space $V$ and $k$ vector subspaces $W_i$

$V=W_1\oplus W_2\oplus...\oplus W_k \iff V=W_1+W_2+...+W_k \wedge dim(V)=dim(W_1)+dim(W_2)+...+dim(W_k)$

I know that in general $dim(V)=dim(W_1)+dim(W_2)+...+dim(W_k) \not \implies V=W_1\oplus W_2\oplus...\oplus W_k$

But I found that definition and I wonder if it is right

Thanks for your help

**Edit** : $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean finite dimensional vector spaces, since this trivially fails for infinite dimensional ones.

**Hint:** Use induction along with the following fact:

> If $U,V$ are subspaces of $W$, then $$\operatorname{dim}(U+V) =\operatorname{dim}U + \operatorname{dim}V - \operatorname{dim}(U\cap V).$$

You should try to prove this fact.

**EDIT:** Here's a basic example of this failing for infinite dimensional spaces: Let $V$ be any infinite dimensional vector space, $W_1$ any non-0 finite subspace (I'm pretty sure any subspace actually works here, but I'm being careful). Let $W_2=V$. Then their sum is all of $V$, the sum of the dimensions is the dimension of $V$, yet the two have non-0 intersection.

Comment: Could you give an example of when this fails for infinite dimensional vector spaces?